# Radius of AddCircle in Leaflet for R

Tags: r, leaflet

```
leaflet() %>%
addTiles() %>%
addCircles(lng = -72.680663, lat = 42.448013, radius = 10, color = "#03F",    weight = 3)
```

Hi! Our group is using the leaflet package. We are trying to figure out what units the radius argument takes in the `addCircles()` function.

According to the documentation, radius is:
a numeric vector of radii for the circles; it can also be a one-sided formula, in which case the radius values are derived from the data (units in meters for circles, and pixels for circle markers)

Is there a way for us to set the units the radius is in? What is the default unit radius is set it?

Circle that shows up with radius of 10 entered:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It looks like meters. According to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrodome#Design_and_construction), the Astrodome has a 110m radius, and if you plot that:

```
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircles(lng = -95.407778, lat = 29.685, radius = 110)
```

it lines up almost perfectly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the projection you are using in Leaflet, it is good to check it with Leaflet's measurement tools or if you know the location well. To see the projections I recommend

```
crsDF <- rgdal::make_EPSG()
View(crsDF)
```

In my case, that I am in Chile (a long and narrow country) I use this projection for some places:

CRS 9155 =

```
"+proj=utm +zone=19 +south +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs"
```

There you can see that I am using units in meters

I don't know where you are but here I leave an image of some projections

```
View(crsDF)
```

[image: View(crsDF]

You can find more in:

- https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/spatial-class.html#projected-coordinate-reference-systems
- https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/spatial-class.html#crs-in-r

Greetings